# Can multiple Spring integration aggregators share the same message store?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have configured the following message store:

```
<bean id="eventMessageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />

<bean id="eventMessageStoreReaper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="eventMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="2000" />
</bean>
```

Can multiple int:aggregatorS safely ref the same message store, or do I need to create a message store for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally need a separate one for each.

If all the aggregators discard expired groups then you can get away with one, but I'd recommend using a separate one for each.

When using persistence, e.g. JDBC, you can share the tables by providing a region for the store, but you still need a separate store instance.